# What are the different PC languages for 2nd edition AD&D?

Tags: adnd-2e, languages

I would like to know what the different languages my PC can automatically have. I play Advanced Dungeons and Dragons 2nd edition and my PC has a 12 Intelligence.

Comment: Most prominent races had their own language and dialects could be picked up for the specific.  Then some races shared goblin tongue, dragon, etc.  But then there were special languages based on the setting.  Do you have a setting in mind?

Answer (score 8):

That entirely depends on the setting your DM is using or has created.

Apart from setting-specific languages, it is typical (though not guaranteed as it's again up to your DM) for there to be one language for each major race; i.e. elvish for elves, goblin for goblins, dwarvish for dwarves, etc., etc. This is typical of AD&D simply because such "racial languages" are mentioned in the write-ups for the playable races in the *Players' Handbook* and the entries for creatures in the *Monstrous Manual*.

When considering what languages to choose, always consult with your DM.

Comment: What other languages can my PC have besides their native tounge and common?

Comment: @Aidan: As I wrote above, you need to ask your DM. Just like in the real world, what languages you can learn depends on the languages that exist. There isn't a "D&D World" with a list of languages that you can choose from, independent from the setting you're playing in.

Comment: Although I will note that depending on your race, there are certain prescribed choices. But if you're human, it's "whatever languages your DM says there are." Weirdly there is a bit of a shared D&D world, because if you're an elf for example the bonus languages you can pick are set to a specific list of "orc, etc..."

Comment: Yeah, but that's often overridden by 2e settings. A complete answer is only available from the DM. There's definitely a D&D genre or implied setting, but it's so much looser and undefined before 3e. If the Q was about default assumptions that'd be one thing, but it sounds like it's about a particular campaign so all bets are off.